# Banach contraction Principle

Tags: real-analysis

Show that there is a positive $\gamma$ and a function $f(x)$ which is continuous on $[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=\sin x+ \gamma \int_a^b e^{xy} f(y) \, dy$ for all $x \in [a,b]$
So for us to use the Banach fixed point theorem we have to be in a complete metric space. Note that $[a,b]$ is compact thus it is complete. Now the hard part is to show that $f$ is $\gamma$ contractive.

Comment: A remark: If you really are supposed to use Banach's fixed-point theorem, then I think you ought to take the underlying space to be not $[a,b]$, but $C([a,b])$, the set of continuous real-valued _functions_ on $[a,b]$. With the supremum norm, the space $C([a,b])$ becomes a Banach space, albeit not compact.

Comment: thanks I think i can come up with a proof now. @triple_sec

Answer (score 1):

Let $B[f](x):= \gamma \int_{a}^{b} e^{xy}f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y$. We can apply the Banach fixed point theorem to $A[f](x):= \sin(x) +B[f](x)$ if $\left\|B\right\| < 1$, as $\left\|A[f] - A[g]\right\| = \left\|B[f]-B[g]\right\|$. To make $\left\|B\right\|_{\infty}<1$, we compute
\begin{align}
\left\|B[f]\right\|_{\infty} 
&:= \gamma\sup_{x\in [a,b]} \left|\int_{a}^{b} e^{xy}f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y \right| \\
&\le \gamma \sup_{x\in [a,b]} \int_{a}^{b} e^{xy}\left|f(y)\right| \, \mathrm{d}y  \\
&\le \gamma \sup_{x\in [a,b]} \int_{a}^{b} e^{xy} \, \mathrm{d}y  \left\|f\right\|_{\infty} \\
&\le \gamma \sup_{x\in [a,b]} \frac{e^{xb}-e^{xa}}{x}\left\|f\right\|_{\infty},
\end{align}
and the latter supremum is attained at $x = b$ if $|b|> |a|$ and $x=a$ if $|a| > |b|$. Then we take
\begin{align}
\gamma < \frac{1}{\sup_{x\in [a,b]} \frac{e^{xb}-e^{xa}}{x}}
\end{align}
to ensure $\left\|B\right\|_{\infty} < 1$.
Since $(C[a,b], \left\|\cdot\right\|_{\infty})$ is a Banach space, we are done.